# Changing xterm color definitions breaks X11

Tags: macos

On my Mac OS X 10.5.8, I changed the color background of the Xterm (X11) by adding the following lines to the file `.Xdefaults`:

```
xterm*Background:               black
xterm*Foreground:               green
xterm*cursorColor:              LightBlue
xterm*pointerShape:             arrow
xterm*pointerColor:             blue
```

It was working well. I did not save other modifications to other files. I switched off the Mac.

The day after, the Xterm just does not open. I click on the icon X11. The bar on the top of the screen shows it is going to open but after a few seconds, it turns back to the previous program and does not open X11. Same result if I try to open it from `Applications/Utilities/X11.app` it just does not open, but NO error messages or other issues to the other programs open.

I tried to check Finder, *Go to Folder*, `/private/etc/paths.d`. It shows `/usr/X11/bin`. This should be correct. So I do not know how to find the error.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the file `.Xdefaults`?

Comment: Does Console.app report anything unusual?

Comment: Hello thanks for youre replies. Unfortunately still does not work:

Comment: I deleted the .Xdefaults and the result does not change. HTere is something unual in the Consol.app, but I have no idea how to use it .

Comment: If X11 is starting up and then dying, /var/log/system.log should contain some indication as to why.

Comment: My /var/log/system.log reports:

Comment: Apr  2 11:08:30 fflt X11.bin[46641]: Incompatible applications: app=org.x.X11, targetApp=com.apple.Safari
Apr  2 11:08:30 fflt org.x.startx[46581]: InitConnectionLimits: MaxClients = 255
Apr  2 11:08:30 fflt org.x.startx[46581]: Xquartz starting:
Apr  2 11:08:30 fflt org.x.startx[46581]: X.Org X Server 1.4.2-apple33
Apr  2 11:08:30 fflt org.x.startx[46581]: Build Date: 20090617
Apr  2 11:08:30 fflt org.x.startx[46581]: 2012-04-02 11:08:30.811 X11.bin[46641:717] Incompatible applications: app=org.x.X11, targetApp=com.apple.Safari

Comment: Apr  2 11:08:30 fflt org.x.startx[46581]: Sync Extension 3.0
Apr  2 11:08:30 fflt org.x.startx[46581]: (EE) XKB: Couldn't open rules file /usr/X11/share/X11/xkb/rules/base
Apr  2 11:08:30 fflt org.x.startx[46581]: (dix) initialising device 0
Apr  2 11:08:30 fflt org.x.startx[46581]: (dix) initialising device 1
Apr  2 11:08:30 fflt org.x.startx[46581]: (dix) initialising device 2
Apr  2 11:08:30 fflt org.x.startx[46581]: (EE) XKB: Couldn't open rules file /usr/X11/share/X11/xkb/rules/base
Apr  2 11:08:30 fflt org.x.startx[46581]: (dix) initialising device 3

Comment: Apr  2 11:08:30 fflt org.x.startx[46581]: (dix) initialising device 4
Apr  2 11:08:30 fflt org.x.startx[46581]: (dix) initialising device 5
Apr  2 11:08:30 fflt org.x.startx[46581]: (dix) initialising device 6
Apr  2 11:08:30 fflt org.x.startx[46581]: (dix) enabling device 0
Apr  2 11:08:30 fflt org.x.startx[46581]: (dix) enabling device 1
Apr  2 11:08:30 fflt org.x.startx[46581]: (dix) enabling device 2
Apr  2 11:08:30 fflt org.x.startx[46581]: (dix) enabling device 3
Apr  2 11:08:30 fflt org.x.startx[46581]: (dix) enabling device 4

Comment: Apr  2 11:08:30 fflt org.x.startx[46581]: (dix) enabling device 5
Apr  2 11:08:30 fflt org.x.startx[46581]: (dix) enabling device 6
Apr  2 11:08:30 fflt org.x.startx[46581]: AllocNewConnection: client index = 1, socket fd = 10
Apr  2 11:08:32 fflt org.x.startx[46581]: font_cache: Done
Apr  2 11:08:32 fflt org.x.startx[46581]: AllocNewConnection: client index = 2, socket fd = 13
Apr  2 11:08:32 fflt org.x.startx[46581]: waiting for X server to shut down

Comment: I cannot understand reading this file but if someone can, it would be very helpful. Thanks!!!